# Combining two bars into one sticky header where top bar changes height

Tags: javascript, css

I have two bars, a top bar and a breadcrumbs bar. The top bar is higher when the two bars are not combined. At some point, the bars combine into one sticky header. The following snippet shows this concept.

```js
$(() => {
  const pivot = 500 - 145;
  $(window).on('scroll', () => {
    const scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('body').toggleClass('after-pivot', scrollTop > pivot);
  });
});
```

```css
.bar {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

.bar:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

.bar.top {
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 85px;
  background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.1);
}

.after-pivot .bar.top {
  background: black;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.bar.breadcrumbs {
  background: red;
  height: 40px;
}

.after-pivot .bar.breadcrumbs {
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
}

.bar>* {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.button {
  height: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background: grey;
  padding: 4px 10px;
}

.image {
  height: 500px;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/2000x500");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  height: 500vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top bar">
  <a href="#" class="button">I am a button</a>
</div>
<div class="image">
</div>
<div class="breadcrumbs bar">
  <span>Home</span> - <span>My weird page</span>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque lacus augue, fermentum sed dui vel, imperdiet pretium risus. Nam quis diam eu tortor efficitur molestie. Nulla non nibh felis. Proin eget malesuada urna, sed bibendum ex. Mauris lacinia
  ligula in ipsum ornare pulvinar. Pellentesque vitae volutpat nibh, in convallis velit. Aenean sed ex massa. Vestibulum ullamcorper purus et erat dignissim tristique. Pellentesque et viverra nisi.</p>
```

However, because the top bar is a different height when it is not combined with the bottom bar, the bottom bar "snaps" in place. If I would change the pivot point to where the bottom bar moves correctly, it will go over the top bar which looks even worse.

```js
$(() => {
  const pivot = 500 - 60;
  $(window).on('scroll', () => {
    const scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('body').toggleClass('after-pivot', scrollTop > pivot);
  });
});
```

```css
.bar {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}

.bar:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

.bar.top {
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 85px;
  background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.1);
}

.after-pivot .bar.top {
  background: black;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.bar.breadcrumbs {
  background: red;
  height: 40px;
}

.after-pivot .bar.breadcrumbs {
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
}

.bar>* {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.button {
  height: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background: grey;
  padding: 4px 10px;
}

.image {
  height: 500px;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/2000x500");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  height: 500vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top bar">
  <a href="#" class="button">I am a button</a>
</div>
<div class="image">
</div>
<div class="breadcrumbs bar">
  <span>Home</span> - <span>My weird page</span>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque lacus augue, fermentum sed dui vel, imperdiet pretium risus. Nam quis diam eu tortor efficitur molestie. Nulla non nibh felis. Proin eget malesuada urna, sed bibendum ex. Mauris lacinia
  ligula in ipsum ornare pulvinar. Pellentesque vitae volutpat nibh, in convallis velit. Aenean sed ex massa. Vestibulum ullamcorper purus et erat dignissim tristique. Pellentesque et viverra nisi.</p>
```

---

What I want to accomplish is that when the bottom bar reaches the top bar, the `margin-top` on the top bar gradually reduces until both bars are at the very top.

I can accomplish this easily enough with javascript by defining two pivot points and calculating the `margin-top` based on this. This would become messy quickly when looking at the responsive site, because I need to move styling into the javascript.

```js
function clamp(min, val, max) {
  return Math.max(min, Math.min(val, max));
}

$(() => {
  const pivotLower = 500 - 60;
  const pivotHigher = 500 - 145;
  $(window).on('scroll', () => {
    const scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.top.bar').css('margin-top', clamp(0, pivotLower - scrollTop, 85));
    $('body').toggleClass('after-pivot', scrollTop > pivotLower);
  });
});
```

```css
.bar {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: background .25s ease;
  transition: background .25s ease;
}

.bar:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

.bar.top {
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 85px;
  background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.1);
}

.after-pivot .bar.top {
  background: black;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.bar.breadcrumbs {
  background: red;
  height: 40px;
}

.after-pivot .bar.breadcrumbs {
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
}

.bar>* {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.button {
  height: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background: grey;
  padding: 4px 10px;
}

.image {
  height: 500px;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/2000x500");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  height: 500vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top bar">
  <a href="#" class="button">I am a button</a>
</div>
<div class="image">
</div>
<div class="breadcrumbs bar">
  <span>Home</span> - <span>My weird page</span>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque lacus augue, fermentum sed dui vel, imperdiet pretium risus. Nam quis diam eu tortor efficitur molestie. Nulla non nibh felis. Proin eget malesuada urna, sed bibendum ex. Mauris lacinia
  ligula in ipsum ornare pulvinar. Pellentesque vitae volutpat nibh, in convallis velit. Aenean sed ex massa. Vestibulum ullamcorper purus et erat dignissim tristique. Pellentesque et viverra nisi.</p>
```

Instead of `margin-top` I could use a real or pseudo-element with a height and alter it's height. We have `min-height` and `max-height`, meaning that if we are somehow able to force some element to be pushed down and thus increase the height of this element, we would be able to make this transition fluid. I am however not able to find any such interaction between a div that is `position: fixed` and an element in the normal flow.

---

**Is it possible to use purely CSS and html structure, plus some javascript that sets one or two classes, to gradually change the margin between the top of the document and the top bar based on scroll height?**

[Codepen to mess with](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/evxprj) if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `absolute` positioning in the CSS, adding a `.before-pivot` class that makes it `fixed` via JS at `ready` as long as `scrollTop < pivot`? After this, during that short period, the `.top.bar` would have absolute positioning until it hits the top part at which point, an `.after-pivot` class would be added. Would still need a `secondPivot` point in order to work but in this case, there's no need for gradual margin decrease.

Basically, the classes of the `.top.bar` transitions from `.before-pivot` to nothing to `.after-pivot`.

```js
$(() => {
  const pivot = 500 - 145;
  const secondPivot = 500 - 60;
  $(window).on('scroll', () => {
    const scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('body').toggleClass('before-pivot', scrollTop < pivot);
    $('body').toggleClass('after-pivot', scrollTop > secondPivot);
  });
  $(window).scroll();
});
```

```css
.bar {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: background .25s ease;
  transition: background .25s ease;
}
.bar:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
.bar.top {
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: calc(440px);
  background: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.1);
}
.before-pivot .bar.top {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 85px;
}
.after-pivot .bar.top {
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.bar.breadcrumbs {
  background: red;
  height: 40px;
}
.after-pivot .bar.breadcrumbs {
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
}
.bar > * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.button {
  height: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background: grey;
  padding: 4px 10px;
}

.image {
  height: 500px;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/2000x500");
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

body {
  height: 500vh;
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top bar">
  <a href="#" class="button">I am a button</a>
</div>
<div class="image">
</div>
<div class="breadcrumbs bar">
  <span>Home</span> - <span>My weird page</span>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque lacus augue, fermentum sed dui vel, imperdiet pretium risus. Nam quis diam eu tortor efficitur molestie. Nulla non nibh felis. Proin eget malesuada urna, sed bibendum ex. Mauris lacinia ligula in ipsum ornare pulvinar. Pellentesque vitae volutpat nibh, in convallis velit. Aenean sed ex massa. Vestibulum ullamcorper purus et erat dignissim tristique. Pellentesque et viverra nisi.</p>

<p>Aliquam vel tempor urna. Ut consectetur, augue non consectetur auctor, quam est blandit dui, quis accumsan sem tortor id nunc. Cras mollis posuere lacus, ultricies placerat metus. Phasellus convallis erat ac nulla semper sollicitudin. Vestibulum lacinia arcu ut efficitur iaculis. Duis in erat vitae mi maximus hendrerit. Mauris ut felis id est pretium porta sit amet eget nunc. Proin posuere fringilla suscipit. Proin eu porttitor magna. Duis convallis rhoncus nisi, sit amet tincidunt turpis fermentum sit amet. Integer sit amet bibendum ligula. Vestibulum nunc felis, facilisis mollis ultrices sed, auctor ut nibh. Nullam suscipit nibh sed tellus commodo, in laoreet dui posuere. Aliquam pulvinar arcu sem, in bibendum augue dapibus at. Quisque mattis, lectus ut ornare dictum, odio urna pretium nibh, at consectetur ipsum magna nec turpis. Cras vel risus eros.</p>

<p>Nunc ante mi, placerat id odio vel, tristique faucibus tortor. Morbi et neque ac velit tincidunt condimentum. Nunc id neque condimentum, pulvinar enim tincidunt, cursus turpis. Sed tempus a ligula accumsan lobortis. Donec consequat dui mauris, vitae hendrerit enim hendrerit sed. Quisque nisl lorem, varius in eros eget, ullamcorper rhoncus sem. Mauris euismod diam eu imperdiet interdum.</p>

<p>Aenean a diam vestibulum, eleifend erat ac, porta magna. In mattis lorem ac libero suscipit luctus a quis tortor. Curabitur quam urna, porta vel faucibus bibendum, efficitur molestie orci. Vivamus ultricies urna dui, ullamcorper aliquam dui semper maximus. Praesent posuere enim massa, eu scelerisque enim tincidunt at. Pellentesque vitae rutrum metus. Nam ac blandit lorem. Sed posuere ornare dui, non imperdiet urna posuere a. Nullam consectetur mi sit amet ornare pulvinar. Nunc laoreet blandit dolor, non elementum purus porta ac. Vestibulum quis auctor quam. Maecenas mi est, ultrices in elit sit amet, congue sodales nunc. Suspendisse eget tristique nulla. Vestibulum vulputate lacus eu nibh porta, ut condimentum diam tristique.</p>

<p>Suspendisse convallis sem dolor, vel congue urna molestie quis. Praesent eros felis, aliquet quis mattis vel, tincidunt vel purus. Pellentesque sollicitudin lorem eu sapien porttitor posuere eget a lacus. In sagittis tincidunt sodales. Cras iaculis velit id elit facilisis lobortis. Maecenas id aliquet elit. Aliquam pretium quam at urna tempus dictum. Cras ornare tellus dolor, ac finibus turpis consectetur ac. Curabitur eget vulputate urna, sed finibus nisi. Quisque molestie, tortor sed sagittis pharetra, dui est suscipit odio, vel venenatis quam sapien vel felis.</p>
```